# bijective function using modular multiplicative inverse

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can we prove that the mapping $f:\mathbb{Z}_N\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_N$ defined as $f(x)=(xR^{-1})\mod N$ is bijective if $N$ and $R$ are co-prime? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just because the map
\begin{align}\mathbf Z/N\mathbf Z &\longrightarrow \mathbf Z/N\mathbf Z\\
x\bmod N&\longmapsto xR^{-1}\bmod N
 \end{align}
has an inverse map:
\begin{align}\mathbf Z/N\mathbf Z &\longrightarrow \mathbf Z/N\mathbf Z\\
x\bmod N&\longmapsto x R\bmod N
 \end{align}
You can easily check that composing them in both orders yields $\;\operatorname{id}_{\mathbf Z/N\mathbf Z}$.

Answer (score 0):

If $N$ and $R$ are coprime, then $aN+bR=1$ for some integers $a$ and $b.$ (To prove this look at the Euclidian algorithm to compute the gcd.) The map $g(x)=x^{-1}b$ is an inverse map to $f(x)=(xR)^{-1},$ from which bijectivity follows.

To see this:
$$
g(f(x)) = g((xR)^{-1}) = xRb = x(1-aN) = x
$$
for all $x\in \mathbb{Z}_N.$ Similarly, $f(g(x)) = x.$

If instead $f(x)=x R^{-1},$ as in the modified question, then the inveser is given by $g(x)=xR.$

Comment: Thanks. There was a typo in the questions. I meant to say $(xR^{-1})\mod N$ instead of $(xR)^{-1}\mod N$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $f(x)=f(y)$.  Then $xR^{-1}=yR^{-1}\pmod N$.  Then $(x-y)R^{-1}=kN$, for $k\in\Bbb Z$.

Now $x-y\cong RkN\pmod N$.  That is, $x\cong y\pmod N$.

Thus $f$ is injective.

Suppose $z\in \Bbb Z_n$.  Then $f(zR)=zRR^{-1}=z$.

Thus $f$ is surjective.

That $R$ and $N$ are coprime guarantees the existence of $R^{-1}$.